# magento 2 How to set attribute value to product during product import

Tags: magento2

I need  to add product attribute value to product during import product programatically how to add this in magento 2?
can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 0):

Upload from the default CSV generated by Magento
Yes you need to fill all your custom attributes into the single column named additional_attributes_code.

Just simply put all your custom attribute in following way into the column with name additional_attributes_code into your imported CSV file.

custom_attribute_code_1="Value_1",custom_attribute_code_2="Value_2",custom_attribute_code_3="Value_3",custom_attribute_code_4="Value_4"

After this simply upload your CSV file.

Comment: yes but this lot of manual work,i need to acheive this in programmatically any idea to this

Answer (score 0):

You need to create product pragmatically like this .

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-product-programmatically.html

And you can assign your customattribute like this. Say for example you have custom attribute having code "custom_attribute1".  than write like below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->setCustomAttribute1("yourvalue");
$product->save();
```

If you want to do after import than perform following steps.

If you want to $productobj after saving product from backend then you can easily use catalog_product_save_after event.

I am assuming that you already know how to create a module in M2.

Put this events.xml in below path

```
app\code\NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\etc\adminhtml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="test_name" instance="NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Observer\ProductUpdateAttribute" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Add following code to PRoductUpdateAttribute.php file

```
   <?php

namespace NAMESPACE\MODULENAME\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class PRoductUpdateAttribute implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();  // product object
        $product->setCustomAttribute1('valuehere');
        $product->save();

    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,but I need magento 2

Comment: yes its for magento 2 only

Comment: I need to add during import programmatically not in csv

Comment: I edited my answer please check it.

Comment: Hi need to update attribute after product import any event..

Comment: Please my edited answer check

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import product attributes programmatically, then you can create a file in the bin folder to run from CLI. You can do as below code, but you have to modify it as your needs. This filename was ***import***, and will run as ***php bin/import***. Remember this file doesn't have an ext name like .php or .phtml as it is a script file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    echo 'bin/import must be run as a CLI application';
    exit(1);
}

echo "Enter Attribute Set Id: ";

$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$attributeSetId = fgets($handle);

echo "Enter Website Id: ";

$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$websiteId = fgets($handle);

echo "Enter Visibility Id: ";

$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$visibilityId = fgets($handle);


use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$file_handle = fopen("pub/media/import/Suppliers_Product.csv", "r");

echo "Product Import started";
$row = null;
$data = [];

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

    if($row == null){
        $row = $line_of_text;
        continue;
    } else {
        $data = array_combine($row, $line_of_text);
    }
    
    $name = trim($data['descript']);

    if(trim($data['sku']) == 0){
        $sku = mt_rand();
    }else{
        $sku = trim($data['sp_sku']);
    }
    
    $price = trim($data['trade_prc']);

    if(trim($data['commodity_code']) == 'NULL'){
        $commodity_code = '';
    }else{
        $commodity_code = trim($data['commodity_code']);
    }

    if(trim($data['cost']) == 'NULL'){
        $cost = '';
    } else {
        $cost = trim($data['cost']);
    }

    if (strpos(trim($data['stock']), '-') !== false) {
        $stock = 0;
    } else {
        $stock = trim($data['stock']);
    }

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

    if($product->getIdBySku($sku)) {
        $products_already_present[] = array_combine($row, $line_of_text);
        continue;   
    }else{
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $_product->setName($name);
        $_product->setTypeId('simple');
        $_product->setAttributeSetId(trim($attributeSetId));
        $_product->setSku($sku);
        $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(trim($websiteId)));
        $_product->setVisibility(trim($visibilityId));
        $_product->setPrice($price);
        $_product->setData('cost', $cost);
        $_product->setData('commodity_code', $commodity_code);
        $_product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                'manage_stock' => 1,          
                'min_sale_qty' => 1,          
                'max_sale_qty' => '',
                'is_in_stock' => 1,
                'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 1,
                'qty' => $stock
                )
            );

        $_product->save();

        echo'.';
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this work after product import every time?

Comment: I need to update this after product import completed then update the attribute of all products

Comment: This is only for products that are already added in Magento and we update attributes. To create Products with attributes you have to change code.

Comment: I am updating the code for that

Comment: You can check the code now

Answer (score 0):

add this additional attribute code before

> $rowData = $this->_prepareRowForDb($rowData);

file path

> /vendor/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import/Entity/AbstractEntity.php

Function

```
protected function _saveValidatedBunches()
    {
        $source = $this->_getSource();
        $currentDataSize = 0;
        $bunchRows = [];
        $startNewBunch = false;
        $nextRowBackup = [];
        $maxDataSize = $this->_resourceHelper->getMaxDataSize();
        $bunchSize = $this->_importExportData->getBunchSize();
        $skuSet = [];

        $source->rewind();
        $this->_dataSourceModel->cleanBunches();

        while ($source->valid() || $bunchRows) {
            if ($startNewBunch || !$source->valid()) {
                $this->_dataSourceModel->saveBunch($this->getEntityTypeCode(), $this->getBehavior(), $bunchRows);

                $bunchRows = $nextRowBackup;
                $currentDataSize = strlen($this->getSerializer()->serialize($bunchRows));
                $startNewBunch = false;
                $nextRowBackup = [];
            }
            if ($source->valid()) {
                try {
                    $rowData = $source->current();
                    if (array_key_exists('sku', $rowData)) {
                        $skuSet[$rowData['sku']] = true;
                    }
                } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
                    $this->addRowError($e->getMessage(), $this->_processedRowsCount);
                    $this->_processedRowsCount++;
                    $source->next();
                    continue;
                }

                $this->_processedRowsCount++;

                if ($this->validateRow($rowData, $source->key())) {
                    // add row to bunch for save

                    $pre_order_qty =  $rowData['qty'];
                    if($rowData['additional_attributes'])
                    {
                        if($rowData['additional_attributes'] != '')
                        {
                            $rowData['additional_attributes'] = $rowData['additional_attributes'].',preorder_custom_qty='.$pre_order_qty;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           $rowData['additional_attributes'] = 'preorder_custom_qty='.$pre_order_qty; 
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $rowData['additional_attributes'] = 'preorder_custom_qty='.$pre_order_qty; 
                    }
                    

                    $rowData = $this->_prepareRowForDb($rowData);

                    


                    $rowSize = strlen($this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($rowData));

                    $isBunchSizeExceeded = $bunchSize > 0 && count($bunchRows) >= $bunchSize;

                    if ($currentDataSize + $rowSize >= $maxDataSize || $isBunchSizeExceeded) {
                        $startNewBunch = true;
                        $nextRowBackup = [$source->key() => $rowData];
                    } else {
                        $bunchRows[$source->key()] = $rowData;
                        $currentDataSize += $rowSize;
                    }
                }
                $source->next();
            }
        }
        $this->_processedEntitiesCount = (count($skuSet)) ? : $this->_processedRowsCount;
                   
                   
   
      
        return $this;
    }
```

the main code is

```
 $pre_order_qty =  $rowData['qty'];
            if($rowData['additional_attributes'])
            {
                if($rowData['additional_attributes'] != '')
                {
                    $rowData['additional_attributes'] = $rowData['additional_attributes'].',preorder_custom_qty='.$pre_order_qty;
                }
                else
                {
                   $rowData['additional_attributes'] = 'preorder_custom_qty='.$pre_order_qty; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $rowData['additional_attributes'] = 'preorder_custom_qty='.$pre_order_qty; 
            }
            

            $rowData = $this->_prepareRowForDb($rowData);
```